# General concept regarding dynamic textboxes on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a project which has a requirement to build "pages" on the fly. A page can consist of various controls like textboxes, checkbox etc. Currently when the user wants to add a new textbox I make a ajax request and render partial view and return the HTML and show it on client side. This works but I also want to handle the data properly when these dynamic controls are filled up by user. In a way if I am not wrong I need to be able to make array of HTML controls. Now if we give static List to our view and generate textboxes using Html.TextboxFor we see that the name generated is something:

```
[0].FruitName
[1].FruitName
[2].FruitName
```

How do I handle this index part when making a Jquery Ajax request so that I always get the correct indexes and render it on client.

If anybody has any better solution than making ajax request then also please let me know. I need to handle the dynamic rendering of HTML controls and also access their values properly when posted back to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `Non-Sequential Indices` at http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx.
He introduced a helper method to generate it as well.
Also, I think you can just pass an index with your ajax call which then gets passed from Controller to your partial view and use it to generate a proper indexed TextBox.

Update:
I've asked a very similar question at [Submit javascript dynamically added elements to controller method like Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10158089/337294)

Comment: yes, that's one of the solution but what happens if the ajax call fails. I have to manually then keep track of it.

Comment: @TomKaufmann You can increment the counter in OnComplete callback event of your ajax call.

Comment: @TomKaufmann: What I meant in the last comment was `OnSuccess`. Guess you already spotted it